IBApi / Difficulties requesting earnings release date information via reqWshEventData
The goal of my Python script is to retrieve earnings release date information from TWS using the WSH reqWshEventData functionality offered by the IBApi python library.
The script runs smoothly without errors until the end but it is not able to receive event data. It is seemingly able to receive meta data but at the next step where it is supposed to apply a JSON filter and retrieve event data it fails to succeed.
Does anyone see what is wrong with it?
import json
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import threading
import time


class IBApiApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.contract_id = None
        self.metadata_received = False
        self.event_data_received = False

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        """Called when connection is established."""
        print("Connected to IBKR. Requesting contract details...")
        self.request_contract_details()

    def error(self, reqId: int, errorCode: int, errorString: str, advancedOrderRejectJson=""):
        print(f"Error. ReqId: {reqId}, Code: {errorCode}, Message: {errorString}")

    def contractDetails(self, reqId, contractDetails):
        """Callback to receive contract details."""
        self.contract_id = contractDetails.contract.conId
        print(f"Retrieved contract ID (conId): {self.contract_id}")

    def contractDetailsEnd(self, reqId):
        """Called when contract details request is completed."""
        if self.contract_id:
            print("Successfully retrieved contract ID. Requesting WSH Metadata...")
            self.request_wsh_metadata()
        else:
            print("No contract ID retrieved. Check API settings and permissions.")
            self.disconnect()

    def wshMetaData(self, reqId: int, data: str):
        """Callback to receive WSH metadata."""
        print(f"WSH Metadata received for request {reqId}: {data}")
        self.metadata_received = True
        # Proceed with event data request if metadata was received
        # Uncomment one of the methods below to test each approach
        # self.request_wsh_event_data_with_conid()
        # self.request_wsh_event_data_with_filter()

    def wshEventData(self, reqId: int, dataJson: str):
        """Callback to receive WSH event data."""
        print(f"WSH Event Data received for request {reqId}: {dataJson}")
        self.event_data_received = True

    def request_contract_details(self):
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "TSLA"  # Change as needed
        contract.secType = "STK"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        contract.currency = "USD"

        self.reqContractDetails(1, contract)

    def request_wsh_metadata(self):
        """Request WSH metadata for the contract."""
        if self.contract_id:
            print("Requesting WSH Metadata...")
            self.reqWshMetaData(1)
        else:
            print("Contract ID not set. Cannot request WSH metadata.")

    def request_wsh_event_data_with_conid(self):
        """Request WSH event data using only the conId, without a JSON filter."""
        print(f"Requesting WSH Event Data using only conId: {self.contract_id}")
        try:
            # Requesting with only the conId as per NB in documentation
            self.reqWshEventData(2, self.contract_id, "")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in requesting WSH Event Data with conId only: {e}")

    def request_wsh_event_data_with_filter(self):
        """Request WSH event data using a JSON filter, without conId."""
        # JSON filter structure as specified in IBKR documentation
        filter_json = json.dumps({
            "wsh_ed": "true",  # Request earnings data
            "country": "ALL",  # Specify all countries
            "limit_region": "10",
            "event_type": {"wshe_eps": "true"}  # Earnings events
        })

        print("Requesting WSH Event Data with JSON filter only:", filter_json)
        try:
            # Requesting with JSON filter only as per NB in documentation
            self.reqWshEventData(2, 0, filter_json)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in requesting WSH Event Data with JSON filter only: {e}")


# Function to run the app in a separate thread
def run_loop(app):
    app.run()


# Initialize and start the app
app = IBApiApp()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 4001, clientId=1)

# Run the IB API in a separate thread to avoid blocking
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, args=(app,))
api_thread.start()

# Timeout management for metadata and event data retrieval
metadata_timeout = 30  # seconds
event_data_timeout = 30  # seconds
start_time = time.time()

# Wait for metadata to be received
while not app.metadata_received and time.time() - start_time < metadata_timeout:
    time.sleep(1)

if app.metadata_received:
    # Reset start time for event data retrieval
    start_time = time.time()
    # Wait for event data to be received
    while not app.event_data_received and time.time() - start_time < event_data_timeout:
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print("WSH Metadata not received within timeout period.")

# Check if event data was received or not
if app.event_data_received:
    print("WSH Event Data successfully retrieved.")
else:
    print("WSH Event Data not found or timed out.")

# Disconnect and clean up
app.disconnect()
api_thread.join()


I had the same issue with the latest version of IB Gateway recently. I would recommend you to make sure that you are using a stable version.

Did you solve this issue then? What version have you been using to manage the issue?

I am using TWS/Gateway version 10.30.1r. WSH requests seem to work as expected in this version.

Would you have the code you are using to get those earnings data back on your end so that I can try to replicate this exactly and see if my issues have to do with my script rather than my IB Gateway software?
